# Build Pipeline is failing with key vault authorization error

Tags: azure-devops

Build pipeline is failing with following error. Please suggest
[image]

I have set up key valut already.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have set up the KeyVault, but the service connection needed to access the keyVault seems to be missing.
If you have created the service connection too, then you just need to authorize the service connection(one time activity), you can try clicking on the **Authorize resources** button (bottom-right in the screenshot).

Comment: Hi Karthik, When I click on authorize connection, it is saying successful authorization is done, but still showing same error.